# I2C LCD w/ buttons - C

Tags: archlinux, i2c, c

I'm have a 16x2 LCD button shield for RPI similar to [Adafruits](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16x2-character-lcd-plus-keypad-for-raspberry-pi/usage). It works using the provided Python library so the setup is ok.

The problem is I can't find any working C code or library to work with this setup. 
I've tried [Gordons tutorial](http://wiringpi.com/examples/adafruit-rgb-lcd-plate-and-wiringpi/) and some other sources I found but with no luck yet.

Has anyone got any working solution for this?

P.S. RPI is running on ArchLinux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this issue. Since I could not migrate the solution python I needed to get it working under C. The solution is to use Python-C API which lets you call python calls and get results.

Most of the information I found in this codeproject [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I)

I created simple methods for my needings which included some "wait for a button press" method and such. For example if I have a method to print on a screen:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python2
>
> from time import sleep
> from Adafruit_CharLCDPlate import Adafruit_CharLCDPlate
> import sys
> btnsleepcycle = 0.01
>
> class lcdSlave():
>
>   def __init__(self):
>       self.lcd = Adafruit_CharLCDPlate()
>       self.lcd.begin(16, 2)
> ```
>
> [Some code ommited]
>
> ```
>   def lcdprint(self, message):
>       self.lcd.clear()
>       self.lcd.message(message)
>       return 0
> ```
>
> [More code ommited]

Now when I want to call the code from my C code I must use the Python-C API call and make an include.

> ```
> #include "python.h"
> ```
>
> The rest is now on your C coding skills but for the same lcd print it is as easy as:
>
> ```
> #include <Python.h>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>     initPython(argv);
>     int result = 0;
>  PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict,
>              *pClass, *pInstance, *pValue, *pMessage;
> // Load the module object
>     pName = PyString_FromString("lcdSlave");
>     pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
> // pDict is a borrowed reference
>     pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
>     pClass = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "lcdSlave");
>     // Create an instance of the class
>     if (PyCallable_Check(pClass))
>     {
>         pInstance = PyObject_CallObject(pClass, NULL);
>     }
>     pName = PyString_FromString("lcdprint");
>     char* msg = "Your message\nhere"; //  '\n' will go straight to 2nd line
>     pMessage = PyString_FromString(msg);
>     pValue = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(pInstance, pName,pMessage, NULL);
>     if (pValue != NULL)
>     {
>         printf("Return of call : %d\n", PyInt_AsLong(pValue));
>         Py_DECREF(pValue);
>         result = 0;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         PyErr_Print();
>         result =-1;
>     }
>     // Clean up
>     Py_DECREF(pModule);
>     Py_DECREF(pName);
>     Py_DECREF(pMessage);
>     Py_Finalize();
>     return result;
>
> }
> ```

**ArchLinux heads-up:** I lost 2 days figuring how to compile this because there is no python-dev package. Found out it's as easy as $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python2) as stated in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104357/73576) solution.